# Why I see this error in Git merge?

Tags: git

When I trying to copy the commit from dev git repository to production respository, I am getting this error
[Here is link of the screen I am getting error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iEA4a.jpg)

I am not sure what this mean.
So I would like to the reason

Thanks

Comment: Please include the error message as text rather than as an image - it's easier for people to read, avoids issues with corporate proxies, and is more friendly to users with screen readers.

Comment: I don't know d-p command. I guess it is an alias ? Please give us the detail of the alias.

Answer (score 0):

This means you have local changes to the file and changes on the git for the same file so you need to "merge" them together.
You can either do that via git directly (only know it from github) or with a git client tool like [git kraken](https://www.gitkraken.com/). Some editors like [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/) or [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org) support that with a GUI aswell.